# Tensorflow 2 model predict is slow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

Initially I described this as problem that gpu is not being used. But now it works. Train phase is faster than previous. Now it takes 4s, but when I was writing quetsion it was 17s. Gpu is used around 10-20% depending on batch and samples size. I used TF1 few years ago, so should work now too.

Predict is slower than training and I am using only danse layers, so im not sure if GPU is used during prediction. I will add more layers so I really would like to know if that is how TF2 works or if there is way to speed things up.

Gpu: `GTX 1070`

Python `3.9`

##### Shortly

- I have installed compatible libraries for Win10 gpu support, which is `TF<2.11`
- Tried TF=2.9.x and 2.10.x no difference.
- Installed `Cudatoolkit` and `Cudnn` using `conda`  in conda environemnt, also versions that are compatible

### Env setup

```bash
conda create -n tf6 python==3.9.16
conda activate tf6
conda install cudatoolkit=11.2.2 -c conda-forge
conda install cudnn=8.1.0 -c conda-forge
pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.9.3
```

### Gpu detect

Whenever I do this test, my gpu has usage spikes up to 100%

```py
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as k2


# from tensorflow.

# from keras import tensorflow as tf

# assert tf.test.is_gpu_available(), "NO GPU"
# print(f"GPU: {tf.test.is_gpu_available()}")
# print(f"GPU: {tf.test.is_gpu_available(cuda_only=False)}")
# print(f"GPU: {tf.test.is_gpu_available(min_cuda_compute_capability=False)}")
# print(f"GPU: {tf.test.is_gpu_available(min_cuda_compute_capability=True)}")



print("CPU LIST:", tf.config.list_physical_devices("CPU"))
print("GPU LIST:", tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU"))
# print("GPU AVAILABLE:", tf.test.is_gpu_available()) # Deprecated
print("Deprecated AVAILABLE:", tf.test.is_gpu_available())  # Deprecated
print("Deprecated AVAILABLE (noCuda):", tf.test.is_gpu_available(cuda_only=False))  # Deprecated
print("Deprecated AVAILABLE (Cuda):", tf.test.is_gpu_available(cuda_only=True))  # Deprecated
print("BUILD WITH CUDA:", tf.test.is_built_with_cuda())  # Installed non gpu package

from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib


print("=== " * 6)
print("LOCAL DEVICES:")
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

```
CPU LIST: [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU')]
GPU LIST: [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
WARNING:tensorflow:From P:\LocalPrograms\stock\friendly_solution_23-07\modules\Check_Env_GPU.py:20: is_gpu_available (from tensorflow.python.framework.test_util) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` instead.
2023-07-06 01:43:49.051838: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Deprecated AVAILABLE: True
Deprecated AVAILABLE (noCuda): True
Deprecated AVAILABLE (Cuda): True
BUILD WITH CUDA: True
=== === === === === === 
LOCAL DEVICES:
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 12081208059895952385
xla_global_id: -1
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 6957301760
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 16955984514207249187
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1"
xla_global_id: 416903419
]
2023-07-06 01:43:49.612956: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1532] Created device /device:GPU:0 with 6635 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1
2023-07-06 01:43:49.614541: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1532] Created device /device:GPU:0 with 6635 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1
2023-07-06 01:43:49.615236: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1532] Created device /device:GPU:0 with 6635 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1
2023-07-06 01:43:49.615928: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1532] Created device /device:GPU:0 with 6635 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1
```

#### Small benchmark

Gpu not utilized, very low %

```py
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import ConvLSTM2D

import numpy as np
import time

# import keras

import tensorflow as tf

size = int(3e4)
N = 500
W_nodes = 600

X = np.random.random((size, N))
Y = np.random.random(size)

print("\n" * 3)
print("Testing model (no session)")
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(W_nodes, input_shape=(N,)))
model.add(Dense(W_nodes))
model.add(Dense(W_nodes))
model.add(Dense(W_nodes))
model.add(Dense(W_nodes))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])

print(f"Fitting X:{X.shape}, Y:{Y.shape}")
t0 = time.time()
model.fit(X, Y, verbose=True, epochs=1, batch_size=10)
model.predict(X)
tend = time.time()
print(f"Time fit i predict: {tend - t0}")

####################

"This was faster for me in other environment, where no session took 17s, and this was around 4"
print("Checking Compat V1 Session")
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.compat.v1.Session():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(W_nodes, input_shape=(N,)))
    model.add(Dense(W_nodes))
    model.add(Dense(W_nodes))
    model.add(Dense(W_nodes))
    model.add(Dense(W_nodes))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])

    print(f"Fitting X:{X.shape}, Y:{Y.shape}")
    t0 = time.time()
    model.fit(X, Y, verbose=True, epochs=1, )
    model.predict(X, verbose=True)
    tend = time.time()
    print(f"Time fit and predict: {tend - t0}")
```

```
Testing model (no session)
2023-07-06 02:30:17.633503: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-07-06 02:30:18.150568: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1532] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6635 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1
Fitting X:(100000, 500), Y:(100000,)
1000/1000 [==============================] - 6s 5ms/step - loss: 4.0560 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
3125/3125 [==============================] - 4s 1ms/step

Time fit i predict: 11.233973741531372
Checking Compat V1 Session
2023-07-06 02:30:29.674981: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1532] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6635 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1
Fitting X:(100000, 500), Y:(100000,)
Train on 100000 samples
2023-07-06 02:30:30.064769: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:354] MLIR V1 optimization pass is not enabled
100000/100000 [==============================] - 13s 128us/sample - loss: 1.1066 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
C:\Users\Greg\anaconda3\envs\tf6\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_v1.py:2067: UserWarning: `Model.state_updates` will be removed in a future version. This property should not be used in TensorFlow 2.0, as `updates` are applied automatically.
  updates=self.state_updates,
Time fit i predict: 17.37589716911316
```

Comment: Increase the batch size by a lot, the default is 32. Also slow is a opinion, it takes 17 seconds to fit and predict 100K samples, that is quite fast to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are measuring training **and** prediction time with your time() block.

> t0 = time.time()
> model.fit(X, Y, verbose=True, epochs=1, batch_size=10)
> model.predict(X)
> tend = time.time()

As expected, you can see that training in TF2 (6s) is faster than TF1 (13s), while predict is around 4-5s in both times. With training and prediction you get 11s (6s+5s) for TF2 and 17s (13s+4s) for TF1.
Also note that you have different batch sizes for your two examples, it looks like your second fit run has a batch size of 1 due to:

> **100000/100000** [==============================] - 13s 128us/sample

This also explains the training time of 13 seconds.
Both your network and your batch size of 10 are small and should in no way utilize your whole GPU. You can try more/larger layers, more data and a larger batch size.

A last note for timing training, the first fit epoch will usually take longer that the next epochs, due to initialization overhead and other background tasks.

Comment: Im dum, I did not think of testing wrong environment. So now I did intentionally install wrong tensorflow with just cpu. And my times are far greater. fit:31s and precit:22s and with session 52s for just training :D.
About the batch yes im aware of that :P

Comment: And also I missed one issue before. Within TF2  v1.Session batch size does not change. So I was watching time per batch, but it was usting `batch=1` and that is the origin of my incorrect time measures, cause one time was 4ms and other 100us